# Compare two dates in two different months with a time frame on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, processbuilder, force.com

I have a scenario where I have two Dates on Account.

Our partners move up to a level above if they buy a product in this month. But the data coming to us shows they moved up in the next month (1st to 10th) as they are processed in this time frame.

For Example

Date1: Joining Date Say 5/12/2017
MovedupDate: Moved up date Say 4/1/2018

I would like to create a flag on Account which say if the Partner moved up to a level within the same Month or the next month 1st to 10th it would come up as 'YES' or '1'.
Please help me with a solution to accomplish this. My first thoughts are Process builder.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below formula to catch all the partners who moved up in this and also the next month <=10 days

AND(YEAR( Moved up date) = YEAR( Joining Date),MONTH( Moved up date ) = MONTH( Joining Date ))
||

AND(YEAR( Moved up date ) = YEAR( Joining Date ),MONTH( Moved up date ) <> MONTH( Joining Date ),DAY(Moved up date) <= 10)

Comment: Changed LogicAND(YEAR( Assistant_Supervisor_Date__c) = YEAR( Enrollment_Date_Formula__c),MONTH( Assistant_Supervisor_Date__c ) = MONTH( Enrollment_Date_Formula__c )) 
|| AND(YEAR( Assistant_Supervisor_Date__c ) = YEAR( Enrollment_Date_Formula__c ),MONTH(Assistant_Supervisor_Date__c ) = (MONTH(Enrollment_Date_Formula__c)+1),DAY(Assistant_Supervisor_Date__c) <= 10)

Comment: What happens when month = 12?